# Dynamically set styles inside @page of CSS3

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set the value of "padding-top" dynamically inside @page?

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <style>
       @page{ padding-top:80px; }
     </style>
    </head>
 </html>
```

I want something like this

```
 <style>
 @page{ padding-top : heightSlider + 30 + 'px' }); 
 </style>
 <script>
 var heightSlider = $('#container_slider').height(); 
 </script>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried this code? And get no result?

Comment: I tried that code and its works for me. But I want something like  "   <script>var heightSlider = $('#container_slider').height(); </script>
@page{  padding-top : heightSlider + 30 + 'px' });  " Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The @page CSS at-rule is used to modify some CSS properties when printing a document. You can't change all CSS properties with @page. **You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document**. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be ignored.

Comment: Is it possible to set dynamic values inside @page.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do it with the use of JavaScript or else when you generate the DOM you can set your value(using php or what ever the language your using to generate the dom).

Comment: Can you give me a sample code of how to do it using jquery or javascript. Please see my recent edit also.

Comment: page will not modify padding mate. you got to find some other solution.

Comment: Actually I am using @page inside VisualforcePage[a different technology which uses apex markup and supports CSS3 completely] and there I am getting full support for  @page{ padding-top:80px; }. I am doing these inside pdf document.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, according to documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40page:

> 'You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of
>   the document.'

So, I don't think its possible to change padding.

Comment: we can change the padding with @page. I have tried that and it works for me. What I want now is, instead of giving the "padding-top" value directly, I wish to give it dynamically.